# Insert Date into Python MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'm trying to insert the current date into MySQL using Python and its MySQLdb module. I can successfully insert the data as such:

```
insert = "INSERT INTO table(utdate) VALUES('2015-12-31')"
```

However, I don't want to hard code the date and would rather use a variable or function like:

```
today = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

I've tried all of the following queries but without success. A successful entry into the database should appear as datetime.date(2016, 01, 01). Below each query is the error message or the resulting entry into the database.

```
insert = "INSERT INTO table(utdate) VALUES(today)"
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'today' in 'field list'")

insert = "INSERT INTO table(utdate) VALUES('today')"
(None)

insert = "INSERT INTO table(utdate) VALUES('%s')" % (today)
(None)

insert = "INSERT INTO table(utdate) VALUES(%s)" % (today)
(None)
```

My hunch is that the issue has to do something with the today variable since it is a string and I must use quotes to insert it. What are your thoughts and suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a prepared statement and the db api will handle the type mapping for you. From the documentation at http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples

```
import MySQLdb
db=MySQLdb.connect(passwd="moonpie",db="thangs")
```

> To perform a query, you first need a cursor, and then you can execute
>   queries on it:

```
c=db.cursor()
max_price=5
c.execute("""SELECT spam, eggs, sausage FROM breakfast
          WHERE price < %s""", (max_price,))
```

> In this example, `max_price=5` Why, then, use `%s` in the string? Because
>   MySQLdb will convert it to a SQL literal value, which is the string
>   '5'. When it's finished, the query will actually say, "`...WHERE price < 5`".
>
> Why the tuple? Because the DB API requires you to pass in any
>   parameters as a sequence. Due to the design of the parser, `(max_price)`
>   is interpreted as using algebraic grouping and simply as max_price and
>   not a tuple. Adding a comma, i.e. `(max_price,)` forces it to make a
>   tuple.

Comment: Thanks pvg! The issue was caused by using c.execute(insert). Using your suggestion of c.execute("INSERT INTO test(utdate) VALUES(%s)", (today)) fixed the problem.